# Nothing seen on hyperterminal

Tags: microcontroller, uart

I am using a PIC16F877A and am reading its ADC value and sending it to the serial port. I am blinking an LED with it so that I can determine whether or not the program is stuck.  Unfortunately, I cannot see any data on the port via Hyperterminal.  However, if I test my code in Proteus, I see data on the virtual terminal.  I know the hardware is designed correctly because it is a commercial testing kit.

I think there is a problem with the crystal settings.

I have also confirmed that the cable is working, because I use the same one for my programmer and this hardware.  I am using the Mikro C pic compiler, with the frequency set to 4MHz.  I tried to edit my project and set the oscillator to HS as well as XT, but the results are the same.  What is wrong?

```
char text[7];

void main() {
  unsigned int adc_value =0;

  UART1_Init(9600);               // Initialize UART module at 9600 bps
  Delay_ms(100);                  // Wait for UART module to stabilize

  ADCON1 = 0x80;              // Configure analog inputs and Vref
  TRISA = 0xFF;               // PORTA is input
  TRISC  = 0;                 // PORTC is output
  TRISB  = 0;                 // PORTB is output

  PORTB = 0;
  UART1_Write_Text("Start");

  Delay_ms(100);
  do
  {
  PORTB.B3 = ~PORTB.B3;

    adc_value = Adc_Read(0); // Get results of AD conversion
    IntToStr(adc_value, text);
    UART1_Write(10);
    UART1_Write(0x90);
    UART1_Write_Text(text);
    UART1_Write_Text("\r\n");
    Delay_us(200);
   // PORTB = adc_value;         // Send lower 8 bits to PORTB
    PORTC = adc_value >> 8;    // Send 2 most significant bits to RC1, RC0

    Delay_ms(100);
  } while(1);
}
```

Comment: What kind of oscillator is in use?  Is it the internal oscillator, or an external crystal or what?

Comment: I suggest you get an oscilloscope trace to check clock error, actual sending of data, logic levels, polarity, etc. Your code looks fine to a cursory reading.  Also, move the `PORTB.B3 = ~PORTB.B3;` to the very end of the while loop so you know your code isn't merely resetting your processor to blink the LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have Hyperterminal set to the correct baud rate, etc? Make sure it isn't waiting for some kind of handshaking that you aren't providing.

Answer (score 1):

I've stopped using Hyperterminal years ago. It doesn't always work as expected. A good terminal program to use is [Docklight](http://www.fuh-edv.de/docklight/) Its very user friendly and has some nice features. The evaluation software will do what you want to do.

Comment: Do you believe that the problem is with Hyperterminal in this case?

Comment: @ Kevin Vermeer - Using a known good terminal program will eliminate the possibly of Hyperterminal errors. I have had issues with Hyperterminal years ago and stopped using it. I can't comment on how good it is now. It's an easy thing to try a new terminal and can save a lot of troubleshooting time. I agree with others that settings need to be checked and data monitored with a scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the settings in your code and Hyperterminal are right, probe the serial pins on the board to see if it is actually sending anything...